# Intel GPU Monitor and Overclocking

Tags: intel, gpu, monitoring, overclocking

I have an Intel Haswell i7 with HD 4800 graphics.

I'm wondering what tools are available for me to monitor and tweak my GPU. I'm looking for something like Nvidia Settings if there is anything like that available for Intel.

I'm already using the Xorg Edgers drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can us the [AMD driver: catalyst](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) instead of Xorg: just specify your system information there. It has the option to control which video card to use and some other options.

But beware, check the compatibility of the driver with your system version. Also remember to get all packages shown on Catalyst's prerequisites if they do support your system.

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear enough, but I was asking about Intel, not AMD :p